# How to write a rewrite rule to hide query string?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am having issues rewriting URLs to hide the query string. I am trying to rewrite:

```
http://seynol.tk/comments?post_referrel_id=16
```

to:

```
http://seynol.tk/comments only
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# to make `/path/index.php` to /path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is check if the query string is set and do a redirect with an empty query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} post_referrel_id
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

If you want to put the referral id in the URL and silently convert it into a query string, you would use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/comments/([0-9]+)$ /comments?post_referrel_id=$1
```

This assumes that the post id is numeric. The URL would look like this: http://sevnol.tk/comments/16

Comment: hey not working.....actually i had tried this this is wiping off the query string not hiding......it anyone help..........

Comment: Yes, the purpose of this is to remove the query string. You can't really hide it. There are other ways to pass the variable if you don't want it to be part of the URL (sessions, cookies, POST, etc) but you can't simply cut it off via htaccess and still have your scripts recognize it.

Comment: my code is successfully hiding the .php extension but i heard that that is a way to hide the query string tooo like
abc.php/fg?56--to----abc.php/56....

Comment: I edited my answer to give the option of including the post id as part of the URL.